# How do I make a square matrix with a 3 column matrix? using R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have to make a square data frame(or matrix) with a 3 column data frame.

My data looks like this.It has 3 columns and 62500 rows(250*250).

```
column1 column2 column3

1       1       11
1       2       12
(...)
1       250     1250
2       1       21
2       2       22
(...)
250     249     250249
250     250     250250
```

What I need to do is to make a new data frame(or matrix) with column3. But the number of rows and columns will be both 250. The first 250 values of column3 will be the first column of the new data. And the next 250 values of column3 will be the second column of the new data. Here's what I am intending.

```
col1  col2 (...)   col250


11    21   (...)   2501
12    22   (...)   2502
(.....................)
1250  2250 (...)   250250
```

Below is what I tried but it doesn't seem to work.

```
data                      #this is my data
result <- data.frame      #this will be my result

for (i in 1:250){
  whattoadd <- c()        #I tried to make values of one column as a vector(whattoadd) 
  x <- (i-1)*250{
      whattoadd <- c(whattoadd, temp[x+j, 3])
  }
  whattoadd <- as.vector(whattoadd)
  result[, i] <- whattoadd
}
```

Comment: like this: `df_new<-matrix(df$column3[1:750], ncol=3, nrow=250)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
set.seed(100)
df <- data.frame(column1 = runif(62500),
                 column2 = runif(62500),
                 column3 = runif(62500))


matrix_c3 <- matrix(data = df$column3, nrow = 250, byrow = F)
```

Comment: You're welcome! If possible, mark it my answer as the correct one :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
matrix(data$column3, nrow = 250, ncol = 250)
```

This will create your new matrix.

Example:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1:16))
matrix(df$a, nrow = 4, ncol = 4)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    5    9   13
[2,]    2    6   10   14
[3,]    3    7   11   15
[4,]    4    8   12   16
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This solved my problem:)